# How to create a function that passes arguments to another bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell

I want to create a function in bash that executes another script with the same arguments passed to the first function.

This is what I've tried so far (I'm getting syntax errors):

**.bashrc**

```bsh
my-fn {
    /home/user/myScript "$@"
}
```

**custom-script**

```
#!/bin/bash

another-defined-fn "$@"
```

I'm getting the following errors when I try to **source** my `.bashrc`

```
-bash: /home/userx/.bashrc: line 206: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
-bash: /home/userx/.bashrc: line 206: `}'
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve this?

**Extra**

How can I include a **sudo** call inside the function?

Something like:

```bsh
my-fn {
    sudo /home/user/myScript "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the right syntax for the arguments, but not for the function definition. You need to define the function like this:

```bsh
myfun() {
   ...
}
```

or this:

```bsh
function myfun {
   ...
}
```

and also to call the function with all the arguments (or a list of arguments).

From a file:

```bsh
myfun "$@"
```

or

```bsh
myfun one two three...
```

Comment: Yes that was it, thank you I was missing the `()` in the function definition, I thought it was optional. Props to @ikkachu too who pointed the same :)